# A universal reflections API?

Tags: reflection

Some time back I was working on an algorithm that processed code, and required a reflections API. We were interested in its implementation for multiple languages, but the reflections API for a language would not work for any other language. So is there any thing like a "universal reflections API" that would work for all languages, or maybe for a few mainstream languages (.NET,Java,Ruby,Python)

If there isnt any, is it possible to build such a thing that can process classes from different languages.

How would you go about having a unified way to process OO code from multiple languages

Comment: I am not understand what you want. A API is ever target to a single language. What do you want do with it? Can you add a sample.

Comment: For example: a multi language Object Browser. U load either .NET/Java/Python classes and it shows u all the members. And the possiblities are endless

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is universal Reflection API. Any Reflection API depends on the metadata that the compiler generates for the language constructs and these can vary quite a lot from language to language, even though there is a common subset across multiple languages.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET there is [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx), which provides a way to generate a universal syntax tree and then serialize it as (C#, VB .NET etc...) code and/or compile it. Of course that's the mirror image of Reflection, but if anyone ever writes a tool to generate the AST directly from IL the functionality could start to overlap.

In any case its the closest thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

A reflection API depends on the metadata generated for the code, so you can have a universal API for all languages on the JVM, or all languages on the CLR...but it wouldn't really be possible to make one that does Python, Java, and VB etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a universal API, you need to step outside the language.  See our [DMS meta-tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) for processing arbitrary languages, and answering arbitrary questions, including those you think of as reflection.
(Op asked for support for various languages: DMS has full parsers for C#, VB.net, Java, and Python. Ruby not yet in the list; we're working on it).